# Mac Apache Ant version 1.8.2 instead of 1.9.6

Tags: apache, ant

I've downloaded the last apache ant version on my Mac but the version seems the old one.
Any idea?

```
myMac:~ mauri$ brew install ant
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ant-1.9.7.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Pouring ant-1.9.7.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7: 1,611 files, 34.9M
myMac:~ mauri$ 
myMac:~ mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ 
myMac:~ mauri$ ./Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ uname -a
Darwin myMac 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Mon Aug 29 20:21:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

here the relative export variables.

```
myMac:~ mauri$ export ANT_HOME=/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6
myMac:~ mauri$ export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
myMac:~ mauri$ export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
myMac:~ mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ /Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ which ant
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant
myMac:~ mauri$
```

here one more command what the core tasks mean?

myMac:~ mauri$ ant -diagnostics

```
------- Ant diagnostics report -------
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

-------------------------------------------
 Implementation Version
-------------------------------------------
core tasks     : 1.8.2 in file:/Library/Java/Extensions/selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar

-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
ant.java.version: 1.7
Is this the Apache Harmony VM? no
Is this the Kaffe VM? no
Is this gij/gcj? no
ant.core.lib: /Library/Java/Extensions/selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar
ant.home: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7

-------------------------------------------
 ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
ant.home: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7
No such directory.

-------------------------------------------
 USER_HOME/.ant/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
user.home: /Users/mauri
No such directory.
```

I've tried to uninstall and install ANT again from brew, but the problem is still the same

```
myMac:OrgSight mauri$ brew uninstall ant
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7... (1,611 files, 34.9M)
myMac:OrgSight mauri$ brew install ant
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ant-1.9.7.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/mauri/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ant-1.9.7.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring ant-1.9.7.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7: 1,611 files, 34.9M
myMac:OrgSight mauri$ which ant
/usr/local/bin/ant
myMac:OrgSight mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:OrgSight mauri$ /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7/bin/ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

Comment: Not sure. You should still be able to download the specific version and install manually, I believe.

Comment: Can you post the output of `which ant`and `brew link -v ant`?

Comment: `myMac:~ mauri$ brew link -v ant

Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7

To relink: brew unlink ant && brew link ant

myMac:~ mauri$ which ant

/usr/local/bin/ant` @Tim

Comment: @Rao `myMac:~ mauri$ cd Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/
myMac:bin mauri$ pwd
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin
myMac:bin mauri$ ./ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010`

Comment: Try uninstalling the previous installation.

Comment: @Rao do you mean the brew? because before using the brew, the output from the ant was the same. I've downloaded the 1.9.6 but actually the output was 1.8.2 as per my previous message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still trying to the reason behind that, but The Ant wrapper script sources some files from /etc if present, so the global installation may leak into your setup regardless. I guess the key is

```
core tasks  : 1.8.2 in
```

file:/Library/Java/Extensions/selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar" - whatever has
put Selenium there, it takes precedence.
I want to thank Stefan Bodewig from Apache ANT for this great insight

```
myMac:~ mauri$ cd /Library/Java/Extensions
myMac:Extensions mauri$ l
total 30536
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel    15M  4 Dez 12:12 selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar
myMac:Extensions mauri$ mv selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar ~/
myMac:Extensions mauri$ which ant
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant
myMac:Extensions mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized after relooking at the post, that you tried to install ant, it has downloaded `ant 1.9.7` version and extraction seemed to be `/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7`.

Or you may use the downloaded directory which is `/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6`

So, all you need to do is to set the environment variables to the right installation path.

Run the following commands on the terminal.

```
export ANT_HOME=/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6
export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now `ant -v` should give right result.

Note that the above changes are only for the command session. If you want to apply it permanently, then update the same in your `~/.bash_profile` file.

**UPDATE:**
If the is continue to persist(i.e., referring to older version of ant), it is possible to have softlink to older version. Try to remove that.

Comment: `myMac:~ mauri$ export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7
myMac:~ mauri$ export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
myMac:~ mauri$ export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
myMac:~ mauri$ 
myMac:~ mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ 
`

Comment: `myMac:~ mauri$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json LICENSE   NOTICE   README   bin   libexec
myMac:~ mauri$ `

Comment: You need to use the appropriate download directory path. May be you can use the directory `/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6` as `ant home`. Please try by re-exporting all the variables or on a new terminal.

Comment: `myMac:~ mauri$ cd Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ pwd
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ export ANT_HOME=/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ export CLASSPATH=$ANT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ which ant
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.6 mauri$ `

Comment: Can you try removing ant 1.8.2 if possible and retry?

Comment: bizarre, isn't?  `myMac:bin mauri$ pwd
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin
myMac:bin mauri$ ./ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:bin mauri$`

Comment: Usually those commands works on windows / linux / ubuntu. See here for more details - https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I've never installed the 1.8.2, so I assume this is a by Default on MAC but I don't know where. I've always played with linux so no much thought here.

Comment: I know that site but no more added value here. All the unix command are above.

Comment: Hmm. not really sure what is so special in mac for not working those commands. If you see that, it was demonstrated different version too.

Comment: @Mauri, what is ant download link you have used for 1.9.6? Do you have any symbolic link to /usr/local/bin/ant? try removing that.

Comment: `myMac:~ mauri$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ant
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mauri  admin  27 13 Dez 20:12 /usr/local/bin/ant -> ../Cellar/ant/1.9.7/bin/ant
myMac:~ mauri$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ant
Password:
myMac:~ mauri$ ant -version
-bash: ant: command not found
myMac:~ mauri$ ./Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
myMac:~ mauri$ `

Comment: no still having the same issue. I've opened a bug on bugzilla because doesn't make sense on mac. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60485