# Can we use Ant jar for ANT_HOME on Windows?

Tags: windows, ant

JAVA_HOME environment variable works fine (java -version works).

ANT_HOME pointing to `C:\antdir\ant-1.8.2.jar` isn't working.

Path command clearly displays that both JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME are added.

`...;C:\javadir\jdk\bin;C:\antdir\ant-1.8.2.jar;`

Is ant jar valid for ANT_HOME configuration?

Comment: Just having the jar available on your PATH isn't enough to run Ant. You need to download the full zip and extract it, then add the `bin` directory to your PATH. https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/

Comment: That's what I did but I wanted to know if the jar is useful that way, too.

Comment: Please add  your statement as answer and if nobody comes in and provides an idea on the jar, I'll accept it.

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132033/mac-apache-ant-version-1-8-2-instead-of-1-9-6/41133625#41133625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, Ant is launched from `ant.bat`, which exists in the bin directory within the downloadable zip. Simply extract the zip to wherever you want ANT_HOME to be, and point your PATH environment variable to its `bin` subdirectory.

Theoretically, you could run Ant straight from the jar, but you'd first have to reproduce much of the complicated configuration that takes place within `ant.bat`. Just adding it to your path wouldn't be enough. Probably wouldn't be worth it unless you have a very specific reason to do so.